# Button click inside row in StaggeredGrid RecyclerView triggers whole item click

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, android-recyclerview

Hi I have a button inside `RecyclerView` row(for Bookmarking). When I click on the button it triggers that button click and also itemclick for the whole row. I have seperate code for handling clicks of the button and the whole item. Why is the buttonclick in the row triggering whole item click?

How can I fix this issue?

Here is my code for button click inside adapter:

```
viewHolder.imgBookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Here is my code for item click of RecyclerView:

```
mGridView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(
        getActivity(), mGridView,
        new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
        ...
    }
}));
```

**RecyclerItemClickListener.java**

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements
    RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    public static interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context,
            final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(
                        e.getX(), e.getY());

                if (childView != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onItemLongClick(childView,
                            recyclerView.getChildPosition(childView));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (childView != null && mListener != null
                && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }
}
```

Comment: When you click on the button inside the row, you're clicking on the row itself so of course it is going to trigger both click events.

Comment: This was not an issue in Listview. I am using this for implementing StaggeredGrid using RecyclerView. Can you help me on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I used touch listener because I want to write click listener for the row in the activity/fragment.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the touch listener for the listitems and using them `ClickListeners` is not a good idea.

 Here is small example for setting the itemClick listener of the `RecyclerView`

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {
public IMyViewHolderClicks mListener;

public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView, IMyViewHolderClicks listener) {
    super(itemLayoutView);
    mListener = listener;
    itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
}
```

**Updated :** 
   Adding the Listener of the button in the list item.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Set the data for the views.
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This will trigger click for whole row. Will this gets triggered when I click on button?

Comment: I want  to write onclick for whole row in activity/fragment. Thats why I used touch listener way.

Comment: That will trigger for the whole item, if you want specifically for a button, add an another button click for the button.

Comment: Can you add the code for IMyViewHolderClicks class?

Comment: Updated my answer have a look @SudheeshMohan

Comment: Please add the code for IMyViewHolderClicks class also. :)

Comment: @Kartheek i think this is the only feasible way to get the click on Item inside Row of Recycler view to work. But some place i read it is bad practise to define itemClicks inside onBiindViewHolder... isn't there other way it can work??